# How to merge partition with gparted?

Tags: linux, partition, gparted, merge

How I can merge all of my three unallocated spaces? And i want the bigger one to be under  `/dev/sda5`.

Gparted screenshot:
[image]

Comment: On which location did you want all of unallocated space to be resided (below to the `/dev/sda7` )?

Comment: @AvinashRaj it better to be resided below sda5.

Comment: @mint - can you please edit your Q so that it explains in more details what you actually want? I see in the screenshot that you've highlighted the unallocated spaces on 3 partitions. Do you intend to have this space consolidated into a single partition? If so is this a new partition or 1 of the 3? Do you intend to have the 3 partitions merged into a new partition w/ all the data on them still intact? Many Q's as a potential answerer means the Q is unclear and should be closed.

Answer (score 4):

***Assuming you're talking about merging 3 partitions into 1 with all the original data intact***

I do not believe you'll be able to merge these partitions, as they are. There is not enough unused space on any of the partitions that can contain the other partitions' used space.

You could shuffle them around and maximize the free space so that it's on 1 of the 3 partitions. With the free space consolidated (on say partition #1), you could then effect the change of moving the data from say partition #2  to partition #1. Then deleting #2 and repeating the steps of consolidating #2's space into #1. This whole dance would have to be repeated to consolidate #3's used space into #1's as well.

Doing the above will require you to enter GParted, make the shuffling changes and then go back to your OS to do the actual file copies that will consolidate the data from partitions #2 and #3 to #1. In between these activities you'll have to go back to GParted to perform additional reshufflings.

Looking at your situation I would consider getting another HDD to execute this operation, the steps are a bit too involved and you'll likely corrupt your data if any are not carried out correctly.

#### Options available through GParted

[image: ss #1]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to move the boxes representing your partitions using the mouse. Do this to make all the unallocted space adjacent, then apply the changes. After it finishes you should have one continous piece of unallocated space that you can use to create new partitions.

Comment: I can't do that by mouse :(

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**

Make sure that all the partitions are unmounted and don't forget to take backup of important datas. If you do the following steps correctly then you don't have to backup anything.

If you want all of your unallocated space under `/dev/sda5`, then you have to follow the below steps.

- Move the unallocated space which was at the bottom to the extended partition by right-clicking on extended pasrtition(`/dev/sda2`) and selecting the Resize/Move option. You can be able to increase it's size. Just increase it by moving the right-arrow to the extreme right.
- Now your unallocated space at the bottom would get inside the extended partition.(just below to `/dev/sda7`).
- Again right-click on the `/dev/sda7` partition and select Resize/Move option. Move the dragger to extreme right so that the unallocated space would come just above to the `/dev/sda7` and combines with the previous one(3+3 GB).
- Right click on the `/dev/sda6` partition and select Resize/Move option. Move the dragger to extreme right so that the unallocated space would come just above to the `/dev/sda6` and combines with the previous one(12.35+6 GB).

Hope it works.

Comment: @AvinashRaj But i don't have Resize/Move option in right click menu.

Comment: Any Other Softwares?